# What's the simpliest way to fetch HTML in a string?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am looking for the very simplie way to fetch HTML body of a remote web site into a string using default C++ libraries or WinAPI.

Comment: I don't agree, that this question is *too broad*, considering that the [Windows HTTP Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) provide fairly high-level support. Voting to reopen. In fact, there is a complete [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384270.aspx#Downloading_resource) on that page, doing exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default C++ libraries to do this.  And I'm not familiar with WinAPI.  But check out the libcurl website here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/.  That site has a listing of "competitor" libraries that may be of use.

Comment: I had few issues with it in VS 2015. It was giving me LNK2001 error.

Comment: That probably means you haven't told VS2015 where to find the libcurl library.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: I did told, well, let me try this once more.

Comment: The question is specifically asking for an implementation that is *"using default C++ libraries or WinAPI"*. libcurl is neither part of the C++ Standard Libraries nor the Windows API.

Comment: @Purixi: Please don't accept an answer, that doesn't address the question. You were asking for a solution, that doesn't use 3rd party libraries. Those solutions exist (see [Remy Lebeau's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33446933/1889329)). This answer provides a link to offsite resources only, by someone who claims to be *"not familiar with WinAPI"*.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsoft's [WinInet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) API:

> The Microsoft Windows Internet (WinINet) application programming interface (API) enables applications to access standard Internet protocols, such as FTP and HTTP. For ease of use, WinINet abstracts these protocols into a high-level interface.

Or Microsoft's [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) API:

> Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP) provides developers with an HTTP client application programming interface (API) to send requests through the HTTP protocol to other HTTP servers.

They are both built into Windows. You simply need to link to either `wininet.dll` or `winhttp.dll`, then `#include` either `wininet.h` or `winhttp.h` in your code, and call the relevant HTTP functions as needed.